# Traefik Forwarding Mailcatcher HTTP to Port 1025 Instead of 1080

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've got a local Docker swarm with a Traefik service routing to other stacks created with compose files. While the stacks were created with compose, Traefik is running as a standalone service:

```
docker service create --name traefik \
  -p 25:25 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
  --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,destination=/var/run/docker.sock \
  --network traefik \
  --constraint=node.role==manager \
  traefik:latest \
  --providers.docker=true \
  --entrypoints.smtp.address=:25 \
  --entrypoints.http.address=:80 \
  --entrypoints.https.address=:443 \
  --log.level=DEBUG
```

I'm simply trying to add Mailcatcher to the swarm as a standalone service. I don't want to use compose.

No matter what I try, Traefik insists on routing http to the SMTP port (1025) instead of the HTTP port (1080). From Traefik logs:

```
msg="Creating load-balancer" entryPointName=http routerName=mailcatcher-1-a4m79pfmvp6ebj0ugv6qiiy7d@docker serviceName=mailcatcher-1-a4m79pfmvp6ebj0ugv6qiiy7d
msg="Creating server 0 http://10.0.0.75:1025" entryPointName=http routerName=mailcatcher-1-a4m79pfmvp6ebj0ugv6qiiy7d@docker serviceName=mailcatcher-1-ri25m46afg6kwmd5yw6yiek3y serverName=0
msg="child http://10.0.0.75:1025 now UP"
```

The most recent thing I tried was to only specify http endpoints and make no mention of smtp or port 1025:

```
docker service create --name mailcatcher --network traefik \
  --label "traefik.enable=true" \
  --label "traefik.http.routers.mailcatcher.rule=Host('mailcatcher.local')" \
  --label "traefik.http.routers.mailcatcher.entrypoints=http" \
  --label "traefik.http.services.mailcatcher.loadbalancer.server.port=1080" \
  --label "traefik.docker.network=traefik" \
  -p 1080 dockage/mailcatcher:0.9.0
```

The issue is staring me in the face from Traefik logs:

```
msg="No entryPoint defined for this router, using the default one(s) instead: [http https smtp]" routerName=mailcatcher-1-ri25m46afg6kwmd5yw6yiek3y
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling swarm mode on the Traefik service did the trick.

```bash
--providers.docker.swarmMode=true
```

Updated create command:

```bash
docker service create --name traefik \
  -p 25:25 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
  --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,destination=/var/run/docker.sock \
  --network traefik \
  --constraint=node.role==manager \
  traefik:latest \
  --providers.docker=true \
  --providers.docker.swarmMode=true \
  --entrypoints.smtp.address=:25 \
  --entrypoints.http.address=:80 \
  --entrypoints.https.address=:443 \
  --log.level=DEBUG
```

Now Traefik is doing the right thing:

```
msg="Creating server 0 http://10.0.8.76:1080" routerName=mailcatcher@docker serviceName=mailcatcher entryPointName=http serverName=0
```

Of course I also had to update the labels for my compose services so that they were under a deploy key (see [swarmMode docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/docker/#services)):

```yaml
services:
  app:
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.roth-mediator-app.rule=Host(`app.local`)"
        - "traefik.http.services.app.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
```